# Is $f_n(x) = (1-x^n)x^2$ uniformly convergent on $[-\frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{2}]$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to develop my intuition for uniform convergence and functional series in general (and so I apologize if this is trivial/wrong).

The question first asks to find the $\text{sup } \{|f_n(x) - f(x)| : x\in [-\frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{2}] \}$ which I am confused about. What is the this $f(x)$? is it the point-wise limit for each $x$ if so are they asking for the least upper bound for the function $f_n(x) - f(x)$ for each fixed $n$?

I am still not sure how to calculate this and if/how this relates to weather $f_(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$.

I'll give my attempt:

for each $x$ in that interval the point-wise limit is $0$. So we need the least upper bound of $|f_n(x)| = |(1-x^n)x^2|$ which I get as $\frac{4}{9}$ (my reasoning is that the term in the bracket converges to 1 since the $x^n$ converges to $0$, so we are left with $x^2$ and the largest value of this is for $x = -2/3$) and thus limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ of the sup exists and so the convergence is uniform.

Comment: Your pointwise limit is correct, now use it to compute the maximum error between $f_n$ and $f(x)=x^2$. ((weather <-> whether))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to guess the limit. You've realized that $x^n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, since $|x|<1$ in $[-2/3,1/2]$. Thus for all $x$, we have 
$$(1-x^n) x^2 \to x^2\ \ \ \text{as }n\to \infty.$$
So you should set $f(x) = x^2$.

Now we find the maximum of $|f_n(x) - f(x)|$, which is 
$$|(1-x^n)x^2 - x^2| = |x^{n+2}| \le \left(\frac 23\right)^{n+2}.$$
Using this you can show that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $x^2$.